# Change -moz-animation starting point?

Tags: css, animation

My current starting point is the default (0°), and was wondering how I start it from a different angle (45° earlier - counterclockwise). Here's what I currently have:

```css
img {
  -moz-animation: 5s rotate infinite linear  ;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation: 5s rotate infinite linear  ;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;  
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0    { -moz-transform: rotate(0); } 
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }  
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%    { -webkit-transform: rotate(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80"/>
```

Thanks.

-Tysuna.

Comment: have you tried to start at -45deg instead 0  and finish at 315 ? 0 still needs the % unit :)

Comment: You could set `transform:rotate(-45deg);` to `img` plus what @GCyrillus said.